# Need Recommendations for Nuclear Reaction Modelling Software

Tags: nuclear-physics, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, software, nuclear-engineering

Working on a project where I need to model nuclear reactions with different fuel pellet shapes. Does anyone have recommendations for software that's good for this? Any advice or experiences are also welcome!

Comment: Sounds like something you have to custom build. Have you spoken with your project manager/research lead on software others have used? What specifically do you want to model?